# UPDATE mysql max value

Tags: mysql, max

I have a field in my database that I don't want to exceed 100. Is there something in a query I can add to make sure it doesn't?

I usually end up doing this:

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + $x
UPDATE table SET field = 100 WHERE field > 100
```

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE table 
  SET field = CASE WHEN field + $x <= 100
                     THEN field + $x
                     ELSE 100
              END ;
```

or:

```
UPDATE table 
  SET field = LEAST(field + $x, 100) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

what about a trigger? something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_limit BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.fld > 100 THEN
            SET NEW.fld = 100;
        END IF;
    END
```